# Python MINIDOM Object How to get only the element name from DOM Object

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I have a python DOM object output, I need to get only the "Elements" from it.

Example:

```
[<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t\t'">, <DOM Element: StartTime at 0x397af30>, <DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t\t'">, <DOM Element: EndTime at 0x397afd0>, <DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">]
```

I need output like

```
StartTime
EndTime
```

Can you please assist ? Thanks

Comment: Example Output : [DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t\t'", DOM Element: StartTime at 0x397af30, DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t\t'", DOM Element: EndTime at 0x397afd, DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">]

Answer (score 3):

> *"I have a python DOM object output, I need to get only the "Elements" from it."*

You can filter your list item where `nodeType == xml.dom.minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE`. For example, assuming that your *'DOM object output'* stored in a variable named `output`, you can do as follow :

```
from xml.dom import minidom
.....
.....
result = [item for item in output if item.nodeType == minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE]
```